# Why is this program returning None?

Tags: python

How can I create a Python custom function to get list of strings having length more than a number `n` when we pass number `n` and list of strings?

I tried using this function but it returns `None`:

```
lst=['shiva', 'patel', 'ram','krishna', 'bran']
filtered_list=[]
def word_remove(n, lst):
    for i in lst:
        if len(i)>n:
            return filtered_list.append(i)
print(word_remove(4,lst))
```

The output is :

```
None
```

Comment: Because `filtered_list.append(i)` returns `None`

Comment: Read the documentation on the `append` method.  Compare it with `extend`, and other methods of adding a member to a list.

Answer (score 1):

`append` method on a list does not return any value. Hence the `None` type.

Answer (score 0):

`Append` function has no return type. Try instead this.

```
def word_remove(n, lst):
    for i in lst:
        if len(i) > n:
            filtered_list.append(i)
    return filtered_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['shiva', 'patel', 'ram','krishna', 'bran']

filtered_list=[]

def word_remove(n, lst):
    for i in lst:
        if len(i)>n:
            filtered_list.append(i)
    return filtered_list

print (word_remove(4,lst))
```

Output:

```
['shiva', 'patel', 'krishna']
```

The method append does not return anything. So you need to return the whole filtered_list.